retrieve all SharePoint groups from a site, then for each group, retrieve its members and adding them to a sharepoint list
I want to automate retrieving data of all  user permission on each of the available SharePoint groups of my SharePoint site, into a SharePoint list that I can use as a matrix for tracking who has access to which folder, also I want to be able to when I make edit permission  on my SharePoint list matrix the change reflect sharepoint immediately and visa versa if a change occurred on SharePoint the change to be sync on the list as well,
now I can retrieve groups and users alone but I can't retrieve the groups dynamically and make an iteration to go through each group and retrieve all its users. can anyone let me know how to do this?
I am new to power automated and not very familiar with its actions so I would appreciate it if you could assist me with creating this flow

did my below answer helped you?

@van Hasan try those steps:-

Use the "Send an HTTP request to SharePoint" action to get all SharePoint groups. The request should be to the endpoint /_api/web/sitegroups.

Within this loop, use another "Send an HTTP request to SharePoint" action to retrieve all users in the current group by calling /_api/web/sitegroups(Id)/users.

Update SharePoint List.



Here’s a step-by-step outline to achieve this using PowerShell:
Connect to SharePoint Online:
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite" -UseWebLogin

Retrieve All SharePoint Groups:
$groups = Get-PnPGroup

Retrieve Members of Each Group and Add to a SharePoint List:
$listName = "YourListName"

foreach ($group in $groups) {
    $members = Get-PnPGroupMember -Identity $group.Title
    foreach ($member in $members) {
        $item = @{
            "Title" = $member.Title
            "Email" = $member.Email
            "Group" = $group.Title
        }
        Add-PnPListItem -List $listName -Values $item
    }
}

Make sure you have the PnP PowerShell module installed. You can install it using:
Install-Module -Name "PnP.PowerShell"

